# Why do we need to pass self as a parameter while calling a class function?

Tags: python

The `self.commands["fetch_messages"](self)` doesn't work if `self` is not passed as an argument.

```
class Some(object):
    def fetch_messages(self):
        print("fetching")

    def send_messages(self):
        print("sending")

    commands = {
        "fetch_messages": fetch_messages,
        "send_messages": send_messages
    }

    def task(self):
        self.commands["fetch_messages"](self)


a = Some()
a.task()
```

Comment: I'd suggest picking up Mark Lutz' Learning Python. This forum isn't here to teach you Python fundamentals.

Comment: The reason you are getting an error is, in your commands dict, values (fetch_messages and send_messages) are not associated with any object, hence when u make a call you need to pass self so it knows which object is making a call.

Comment: @BradenHolt - Does that reference talk about the difference between functions and bound methods?

Comment: @tdelaney Yes. You can find that discussion in the "Designing with Classes" chapter.

Answer (score 0):

When you call a method on an object, `self` is passed to the function automatically, and doesn't need to be specified as an argument by the caller.  You would get that behavior if the function you were invoking was `self.fetch_messages`.  You aren't accessing it as a method of a particular object, though; you're just giving the name of the function within the class definition, so there is no `self`.  Hence you need to pass one.

One way to observe the difference is to use `reveal_type` with `mypy`:

```
    commands = {
        "fetch_messages": fetch_messages,
        "send_messages": send_messages
    }
    reveal_type(fetch_messages)           # Revealed type is 'def (self: main.Some)' 

    def task(self) -> None:
        reveal_type(self.fetch_messages)  # Revealed type is 'def ()'
```

The type of `self.fetch_messages` is `Callable[[], None]` (no argument), whereas the type of `Some.fetch_messages` is `Callable[[Some], None]` (requires a `Some` argument).

The dispatch table type thing you're doing would work if you implemented it as:

```
from typing import Dict, Callable

...

    def task(self):
        commands: Dict[str, Callable[[], None]] = {
            "fetch_messages": self.fetch_messages,
            "send_messages": self.send_messages
        }
        self.commands["fetch_messages"]()
```

If you wanted to share the dispatch table across multiple methods, you could define it in the `__init__` -- the crucial thing is that it has to be defined per-instance (not as a class variable) if you want it to be bound to a particular instance.